# will downloading ubuntu erase windows? And what will happen to my files (pictures, documents etc.)

Tags: dual-boot

Will installing Ubuntu erase Windows? What will happen to my files (pictures, documents etc.) 
What will the installation do automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is substantial documentation on dual-booting [Ubuntu with Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) which I strongly recommend if you are new to Linux because it allows you to boot your old system if needed.

By the time you're ready for your second Ubuntu installation, you'll probably realize that you don't need Windows except possibly as a gaming platform.